# Windows 10 upgrade affects accessing SVN with NTLM

Tags: windows, svn

We were on SVN Server 1.7.1 + apache 2.22 & SVN client on 1.67 .. Users are on Windows 7 OS & were able to authenticate SVN with the below settings on NTLM.
 1.Security settings ----- > Local Policies ----- > Security Options --- > Lan Manager authentication level - should be set to the option send NTLM and NTLM responses
 2.Security settings ----- > Local Policies ----- > Security Options --- > Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based (including secure RPC) clients – both the options (Require NTLMv2 session security, Require 128-bit encryption) should be unchecked

But now when our OS is upgraded to WINDOWS 10 the above options were not to provided to disable , hence users upgraded to Windows 10 were not able to access SVN..

We are not sure of how to work with NTLM & which are the settings that we have to work on for the users to wotrk on..

Someone could check & provide possible solution on this..

Answer (score 0):

You should plan to upgrade your server and clients. There is a great chance that the problem that you've encountered has been already fixed. The versions that you use now are very outdated and haven't been supported for years -- Apache Subversion project does not release any patch updates to SVN 1.6.x since 2011. BTW, you could at least apply the latest patch updates in SVN 1.7.x and 1.6.x versions that are 1.6.23 and 1.7.22.

Since you are on Windows, you could try switching to [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/). The product should make it much more easier to maintain and administer SVN server in your environment. Applying patch updates to VisualSVN Server is very simple -- download the Windows Installer package and run it on the server computer. I'm with VisualSVN Team so consider me biased. :)

Moreover, the product is designed to be used in Windows and Active Directory environment and fully supports [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/) (Kerberos or NTLM via Negotiate).

> We are not sure of how to work with NTLM & which are the settings that
>   we have to work on for the users to wotrk on.

Contact the server's admin. He should know what authentication methods are configured on the server. Normally, your server should support Kerberos authentication which is a de-facto standard in Active Directory since Windows 2000. NTLM is just a fallback option.